# AppArg property is cached (iOS simulator) and is presented anew

Tags: java, ios, dictionary, codenameone, lifecycle

My CN1 iOS app can respond to the user selecting files with a custom extension.

This kind of code is used:

```
String arg=Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg",null);
```

inside the

```
start()
```

method.

The method is correctly called, and the AppArg property bears the right url value.

The build hint fot this functionality is:

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key><string>YES</string><key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key><array> <dict><key>UTTypeDescription</key><string>List of myapp</string><key>UTTypeConformsTo</key><array><string>public.json</string><string>public.database</string><string>public.data</string><string>public.text</string><string>public.content</string></array><key>UTTypeIdentifier</key><string>com.myapp.queries</string><key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key><dict><key>public.filename-extension</key><array><string>ext</string></array><key>public.mime-type</key><array><string>application/json</string> </array> </dict> </dict> </array><key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key><array><string>comgooglemaps</string></array><key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleTypeRole</key><string>Viewer</string><key>LSItemContentTypes</key><array><string>com.myapp.queries</string></array><key>CFBundleIdentifier</key><string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string><key>LSHandlerRank</key><string>Default</string><key>CFBundleTypeName</key><array><string>com.myapp.queries</string></array><key>NSUbiquitousDocumentUserActivityType</key><string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER).queries</string></dict></array><key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key><array><dict><key>UTTypeConformsTo</key><array><string>public.json</string><string>public.database</string><string>public.data</string><string>public.text</string><string>public.content</string></array><key>UTTypeDescription</key><string>List of myapp</string><key>UTTypeIdentifier</key><string>com.myapp.queries</string><key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key><dict><key>public.filename-extension</key><array><string>ext</string></array></dict></dict></array>
```

I am testing on iOS simulator and I see that the AppArg stays as a property value also when the start() method is called again for whatever reason, including simple foregrounding of the app with no launch options.

I tried to erase the value with something like:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("AppArg", null);
```

after it is read, but the app will be compelled to import the same data again because the value is not null: it is the same value instead.

I would like to know whether it is something from the OS or from CN1

and

how to set that value to null for every next time, unless a real value is provided after a real action by the user.

In fact, it is not uncommon that the user selects the same file (for example after cancelling the previous attempt) so it does not make sense to check the value whether it is different or not, because in both cases it would be legit, so another check is necessary.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the source it's sent from the OS again. What sort of operation are you taking that triggers start to get invoked again?

Comment: @Shai Almog Is it sure that when the OS foregrounds the app again with no launch options the property is  correctly set? I mean, if it is null, maybe CN1 code thinks it is setting it to null but instead the old value remains? Can it be checked or the null value enforced more strongly, possibly from within the Java app itself? Indeed setting to null seems not to be effective, maybe it is also in CN1 passing code.

Comment: If you have it on xcode you can just set a breakpoint in the code and see if it's invoked from the OS and if our reset code is invoked. See https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m#L235 and https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m#L132

Comment: @Shai Almog It is clear from inspecting the CN1 code that when the url is null it is not updated, so it is inside the dictionary yet. The fact is that if I even set it to null manually with setProperty(), when the time comes that start() is called again the value is still in the dictionary. How to set it to null? Is it another value (like "") suitable instead to circumvent this issue for now?

Comment: Setting to null will delete the value. That should work. You can verify this by getting the value again and seeing that it's null now. This means someone else is setting the value back. I suggest stepping into the xcode method for the setting the value and placing a breakpoint there. Then look at the code sections that invoke set after you set it to null. While the C code isn't exactly readable, the class names and call stacks should point you to the code that's resetting the value.

Comment: @Shai Almog It seems that  there are two "parallel" levels of data structures, one on the OS side, and another on the Java side. When the Java code sets the property to null, it is set only in the Java-side data level. They are out of sync and the old value is still present in the data OS-side?

Comment: No. It's a simple Java hash map and app put operations go to it from the same place. You can see the code in IOSImplementation.java 6174. Notice that other properties have special cases but AppArg falls back to using the default hash map base class.

Comment: @Shai Almog It seems that the willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is not always called when the app is foregrounded to welcome an url. So it can happens both that the same url is "presented again" when no url at all was sent by the OS and also that no url is presented when a file is chosen. It seems that the start() chain can also begin in another place (traces back to thread stuff I cannot understand), although at the right time, but it has a reference to an "old object" that is the first "options" object passed to the the app at the very launch moment.

Comment: OK. Is there a way to detect that double invocation or a way to detect that the app was invoked with a file in the other case?

Comment: @Shai Almog Yes, you can reproduce it very easily. I edited the question to provide the build hint for the functionality, you just inject it in a sample app you already have on the hard disk. Replace 'myapp' with the name of the sample app, and 'ext' with an extension you have a file to test on the simulator. Then you just try to open that file more than one time in different and/or  the same ways, or also drag/drop from the computer to the iOS home screen or the Files app, or the app itself. There is no double invocation at the same time, just at different times.

Comment: You already have a test case running in that environment with a debugger. I'm guessing there's a simple if we can stick in our native callbacks to detect the misfires. That should be pretty easy for you to detect.

Comment: @Shai Almog As I said, tracing back is not possible in the debugger because the calls originates in the threading stuff. However it is not necessary to debug. You can inspect the code of any CN1 iOS-compiled project searching for text symbols and you will find that in many places the app is managing the CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG object (or its counterparts) like applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillEnterForeground/Background, start, main, run and so on. Studying such a complex system is not practical or sensible for me.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with threading. There are two. Native and EDT. The native thread is always invoked for the callbacks where you set the app args with the exception of setting it to null which is on the EDT and shouldn't be relevant. What matters is why this is set again after it was cleared and wasn't invoked again. Which stack called it.That should happen on the native thread. If there's a race condition this could be the problem.

Comment: @Shai Almog I don't know if threads are involved, in fact the system you describe is prone to issues as the one that is dealt with here, I think. Only you can know where a "stale" object could be nested. I am not willing to study CN1 internals, and my comment just means that I cannot see which methods call happen too early in the stack trace of the start() method, that you asked me to report here, because they are not provided, I do not see them, I see threading stuff in the early back trace.

Comment: OK. File an issue but I'm not sure when we'll get around to debug this. We have a very deep pipeline and this is an edge case in a native environment.